# change font size array php code

Tags: php

Hi this is a part of my php code, I'd like to change the font size of my array $ora and $p but the text use the default font size even if i modify it. Could you help me?? Thank you.

```
echo "<table>";
for ($i = 0; $i < $count-1; $i++) {
    echo '<font size="28" ><td width="150" align=left>' .$ora[$i].'</td></font>';
    echo '<td width="300" align=center>'.$p[$i].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo "</table>";
```

EDIT:

I tried this way:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
echo '<style type="text/css">
.bold {
font-weight:bold;
}
</style>'; 
[...]
echo '<span class=\"bold\"><td width="150" align=left>' .$ora[$i].'</td></span>';
```

but it doesnt work, any help??

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using CSS? `<font>` tags have long since been considered deprecated & a bad practice. For an introduction in CSS, see: http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/tutorials

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
echo "<table>";
for ($i = 0; $i < $count-1; $i++) {
    echo '<td width="150" align=left style="font-size:28px;">' .$ora[$i].'</td>';
    echo '<td width="300" align=center style="font-size:30px;">'.$p[$i].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS.   Add

```
Style="font-size:125%"
```

to the places you'd like to enlarge.

Answer (score 0):

It should be this way:

```
    echo "<table>";
for ($i = 0; $i < $count-1; $i++) {
echo '<td width="150" align=left><font size="28" >' .$ora[$i].'</font></td>';
echo '<td width="300" align=center><font size="28" >'.$p[$i].'</td>';
echo '</tr>';
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute this and you will get your solution.

```
<?php
$count = 10;
$ora=array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota","Volvo","BMW","Toyota",
     "Volvo","BMW","Toyota","Volvo","BMW","Toyota");
$p=array("1","2","3","1","2","3","1","2","3","1","2","3");
echo "<table border = 1>";
for ($i = 0; $i < $count - 1; $i++) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td width="150" align=left><font size="28" >' .$ora[$i].'</font></td>';
    echo '<td width="300" align=center>'.$p[$i].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that you should use `css`, the real problem, in both examples you provided, is that you wrap the `<font>` tag or the `<span>` tag around the `<td>` tag. This is not correct, because the only permitted parent for the `<td>` tag is a `<tr>` tag.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td

Because of that, your  tag gets stripped by the browser.

To test it, if I open this file in my browser:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <font size="28">
            <td>td</td>
        </font>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and than i inspect the element using `F12`, i see:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>td</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

`<font>` tag is gone. On the other hand, if I open this file:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <font size="28">td</font>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

the inspector shows:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <font size="28">td</font>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```